# Efficient way of generating new columns having string similarity distances between two string columns

Tags: python, pandas, levenshtein-distance, difflib

I have a pandas dataframe with shape `(1138812, 14)` and columns

```
['id', 'name', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'address', 'city', 'state',
       'zip', 'country', 'url', 'phone', 'categories', 'point_of_interest',
       'id_2', 'name_2', 'latitude_2', 'longitude_2', 'address_2', 'city_2',
       'state_2', 'zip_2', 'country_2', 'url_2', 'phone_2', 'categories_2',
       'point_of_interest_2', 'match']
```

I want to create new columns based on the string similarity distances using [Levenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/Levenshtein/) and [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#module-difflib) `difflib.SequenceMatcher().ratio()`, `Levenshtein.distance()`, `Levenshtein.jaro_winkler()` and `LongestCommonSubstring()` between each of the columns

```py
['name', 'address', 'city', 'state',
       zip', 'country', 'url', 'phone', 'categories']
```

and corresponding `_2` suffixed columns. In the end it will give me 9*4 = 36 new columns.
Right now, I am using `df.iterrows()` to loop through the dataframe and make column lists. But it is very very time and memory consuming. It takes 3.5 hours to go through the whole dataframe while using full 16GB ram memory. I am trying to find a better method both time and memory wise to get my result.
My code:

```
import Levenshtein
import difflib
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
columns = ['name', 'address', 'city', 'state',
           'zip', 'country', 'url', 'phone', 'categories']
data_dict = {}
for i in columns:
    data_dict[f"{i}_geshs"] = []
    data_dict[f"{i}_levens"] = []
    data_dict[f"{i}_jaros"] = []
    data_dict[f"{i}_lcss"] = []
for i,row in tqdm(train.iterrows(),total = train.shape[0]):
    for j in columns:
        data_dict[f"{j}_geshs"].append(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, row[j], row[f"{j}_2"]).ratio())
        data_dict[f"{j}_levens"].append(Levenshtein.distance(row[j], row[f"{j}_2"]))
        data_dict[f"{j}_jaros"].append(Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(row[j], row[f"{j}_2"]))
        data_dict[f"{j}_lcss"].append(LCS(str(row[j]), str(row[f"{j}_2"])))
data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
train = pd.concat(train, data, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with a dataframe that looks like:

| first_name | address | city | state | zip | url | phone | categories | first_name_2 | address_2 | city_2 | state_2 | zip_2 | url_2 | phone_2 | categories_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rori | 680 Buell Crossing | Dallas | Texas | 75277 | [url_shortened](https://spiegel.de/nullam/porttitor/lacus/at/turpis/donec/posuere.js?ipsum=duis&primis=bibendum&in=morbi&faucibus=non&orci=quam&luctus=nec&et=dui&ultrices=luctus&posuere=rutrum&cubilia=nulla&curae=tellus&donec=in&pharetra=sagittis&magna=dui&vestibulum=vel&aliquet=nisl&ultrices=duis&erat=ac&tortor=nibh&sollicitudin=fusce&mi=lacus&sit=purus&amet=aliquet&lobortis=at&sapien=feugiat&sapien=non&non=pretium&mi=quis&integer=lectus&ac=suspendisse&neque=potenti&duis=in&bibendum=eleifend&morbi=quam&non=a&quam=odio&nec=in&dui=hac&luctus=habitasse&rutrum=platea&nulla=dictumst&tellus=maecenas&in=ut&sagittis=massa&dui=quis&vel=augue) | 214-533-2179 | Granite Surfaces | Agustin | 7 Schiller Crossing | Lubbock | Texas | 79410 | [url_shortened](https://cnn.com/faucibus/orci/luctus/et/ultrices/posuere/cubilia.xml?in=posuere&purus=felis&eu=sed&magna=lacus&vulputate=morbi&luctus=sem&cum=mauris&sociis=laoreet&natoque=ut&penatibus=rhoncus&et=aliquet&magnis=pulvinar&dis=sed&parturient=nisl&montes=nunc&nascetur=rhoncus&ridiculus=dui&mus=vel&vivamus=sem&vestibulum=sed&sagittis=sagittis&sapien=nam&cum=congue&sociis=risus&natoque=semper&penatibus=porta&et=volutpat&magnis=quam&dis=pede&parturient=lobortis&montes=ligula&nascetur=sit&ridiculus=amet&mus=eleifend&etiam=pede&vel=libero&augue=quis&vestibulum=orci&rutrum=nullam&rutrum=molestie&neque=nibh&aenean=in&auctor=lectus&gravida=pellentesque&sem=at&praesent=nulla&id=suspendisse&massa=potenti&id=cras&nisl=in&venenatis=purus&lacinia=eu&aenean=magna&sit=vulputate&amet=luctus&justo=cum&morbi=sociis&ut=natoque&odio=penatibus&cras=et&mi=magnis&pede=dis) | 806-729-7419 | Roofing (Metal) |
| Dmitri | 05 Coolidge Way | Charleston | West Virginia | 25356 | [url_shortened](http://si.edu/primis/in/faucibus/orci/luctus.html?velit=interdum&vivamus=mauris&vel=non&nulla=ligula&eget=pellentesque&eros=ultrices&elementum=phasellus&pellentesque=id&quisque=sapien&porta=in&volutpat=sapien&erat=iaculis&quisque=congue&erat=vivamus&eros=metus&viverra=arcu&eget=adipiscing&congue=molestie&eget=hendrerit&semper=at&rutrum=vulputate&nulla=vitae&nunc=nisl&purus=aenean&phasellus=lectus&in=pellentesque&felis=eget&donec=nunc&semper=donec&sapien=quis&a=orci&libero=eget&nam=orci&dui=vehicula&proin=condimentum&leo=curabitur&odio=in&porttitor=libero&id=ut&consequat=massa&in=volutpat&consequat=convallis&ut=morbi&nulla=odio) | 304-906-6384 | Structural and Misc Steel (Fabrication) | Kearney | 0547 Clemons Plaza | Peoria | Illinois | 61651 | [url_shortened](https://over-blog.com/nibh/in/lectus/pellentesque.png?pulvinar=libero&lobortis=ut&est=massa&phasellus=volutpat&sit=convallis&amet=morbi&erat=odio&nulla=odio&tempus=elementum&vivamus=eu&in=interdum&felis=eu&eu=tincidunt&sapien=in&cursus=leo&vestibulum=maecenas&proin=pulvinar&eu=lobortis&mi=est&nulla=phasellus&ac=sit) | 309-326-4252 | Framing (Steel) |

And is of shape `1024000 rows × 16 columns`

```py
import difflib
import Levenshtein
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize(nb_workers=8) # Customize based on # of cores, or leave blank to use all

def dists(x, y):
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x, y)
    geshs = matcher.ratio()
    levens = Levenshtein.distance(x, y)
    jaros = Levenshtein.jaro_winkler(x, y)
    lcss = matcher.find_longest_match(0, len(x), len(y)) # I wasn't sure how you'd done this one.
    return [geshs, levens, jaros, lcss]


df = pd.read_csv('MOCK_DATA.csv')
df = df.astype(str) # force all fields to strings.

cols = df.columns
cols = np.array_split(cols, 2) # assumes there's a matching `_2` column for every column.
for x, y in zip(*cols):
    (df[x + '_geshs'], 
     df[x + '_levens'], 
     df[x + '_jaros'], 
     df[x + '_lcss']) = df.parallel_apply(lambda z: dists(z[x], z[y]), axis=1, result_type='expand')
    # Replace parallel_apply with apply to run non-parallel.
```

(In addition to keeping the original columns) I get these columns in 3 minutes, without parallezation, it would still probably only take ~20-30 minutes. Peak memory usage from python was only about 3GB, and would be *much* lower without parallezation.

| first_name_geshs | first_name_levens | first_name_jaros | first_name_lcss | address_geshs | address_levens | address_jaros | address_lcss | city_geshs | city_levens | city_jaros | city_lcss | state_geshs | state_levens | state_jaros | state_lcss | zip_geshs | zip_levens | zip_jaros | zip_lcss | url_geshs | url_levens | url_jaros | url_lcss | phone_geshs | phone_levens | phone_jaros | phone_lcss | categories_geshs | categories_levens | categories_jaros | categories_lcss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |